# Do I need a transit visa? (Schengen)

Tags: visas, transit, norway, algerian-citizens, transit-visas

I am an **Algerian national** and I have been granted a **Norway Schengen entry visa** (single entry) valid for one month only because I will be getting a student residence permit once I'm in Norway.

The issue is that I am traveling from **Algeria** to **Germany** (stopover) and then to **Norway** on the same day (Lufthansa). Do I need a transit visa when I enter Germany?

**My visa indicates that it is only for Norway (first line in the visa).**

**VISA TYPE: D**

NON-DUPLICATE Explanation:
My visa is valid only for Norway. It is not for the whole Schengen area. If it was for the whole Schengen are, then I would not need a transit visa because I already did it.

Comment: Supposedly you don't need a transit visa for Germany if you hold a valid visa for _any_ other Schengen member state, regardless of its territorial validity. But I haven't yet located the official proof of this.

Comment: Unless I missed something, the "duplicate" doesn't seem to cover limited territorial validity visas, and so isn't really a duplicate. If I did miss something, please clarify it for all of us.

Comment: One more point, if you do stay at the airport when in Germany, would you ever need a visa? I don't think so. But it's something to double check.

Comment: Did you ask at the German consulate?

Comment: @AdrienBe Yes, because the OP needs to enter the Schengen area there.

Comment: @Relaxed always thought that airports had a special status, like international territories

Comment: @AdrienBe Some parts of some airports do have a sort of special status but only because the country that hosts them wants it that way. So it's sometimes possible to transit without a visa even if would need one to enter the country but it's not always the case. It can be restricted to specific airports, specific flights, people with a certain citizenship, etc. In this particular case, there are some people who need a visa for any transit even if most people don't and many more people who need a visa if they want to do a transit within the Schengen area (the OP's case).

Answer (score 2):

If your visa is really only valid for Norway, then you do need another visa to go through Germany (and it needs to be a regular Schengen visa or possibly a special German visa but not merely an “airport transit visa” because you need to be able to enter the Schengen area in Germany). If you had such a visa, it would actually be more likely that you would be forced to avoid transiting in Germany completely because they are intended for people who are not eligible for a regular uniform visa.

But I am not convinced that this is actually the case of your visa. My understanding is that a “type D” visa is always a long-stay visa that covers the rest of the Schengen area, at least for transit. Some do say so explicitly on the sticker (with mentions like “Italia + STATI Schengen” or “France + 1 transit Schengen”), some don't and most would be valid for longer than three months (let alone one) but it could still be the case even if it only says “Norway” and “1 month”.

So I suspect your visa isn't actually restricted to Norway and I would first try to ascertain this by contacting the Norwegian and/or German consulates.

Comment: Tanks or your reply. In fact, I called the Norwegian embassy today and the answer of the representative was just: "Of course you can have a stopover, you have a visa to another Schengen country". I might check with the German embassy as well. This is because an Indian friend faced this issue and is planning to have his stopover outside of the Schengen country.